# Can I use a Murder to kill a planeswalker if it is a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Assume the other player has used [Sarkhan the Masterless](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSarkhan%20the%20Masterless%5d) +1 to turn all of their planeswalkers into 4/4 Dragons can I cast [Murder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=447246) and destroy one of the planeswalkers, since they become creatures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly how it works. Note that Sarkhan makes them not planeswalkers anymore (until end of turn), but even if they'd become a creature *in addition* to being a planeswalker, Murder would still work.

Comment: Small caveat: the most common planeswalker that turns into a creature is Gideon, and Gideon usually turns into an indestructible creature, which will not die to Murder.